# Run a scheduled windows task only if a specific program is running

Tags: windows, batch-file, events, triggers

I have Windows task scheduler set up to run a batch file that launches Firefox and runs a macro inside it.

The task is scheduled for weekdays at a specific time, and I want it to check if my messenger program is running before it activates. Kind of like a failsafe, if the messenger program isn't already running in the first place, I don't need the scheduler to launch Firefox.

Is this possible with some kind of trigger/argument I could add? Maybe even to the batch file itself? How would you suggest I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this to figure out if the firefox is on running 
`tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq firefox.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "firefox.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Programm is running`